# Any ideas what the work by Tim Booth may be influenced by?

Tags: portrait

I'm doing a project for "A Level" photography, looking at taking my own photographs like Tim Booth, but struggling to find any related photographers. I found the work of [John Coplans](http://www.artnet.com/artists/john-coplans/), but just wondering if anybody else had some names that may relate to Tim Booth's [portraits of hands](https://www.timbooth.com/portfolio_category/a-show-of-hands/).

Comment: https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&id=5890E03352BBE8B90E12848C4BDA9970AD518596&thid=OIP.bM4ZF70OF2SyzJcuMNKQyADrEJ&mediaurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdominiktomczyk.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F01%2FShow-of-Hands-ASOH-Jacket.jpg&exph=1024&expw=908&q=tim+booth+hands&selectedindex=17&ajaxhist=0&vt=3&eim=1,6&ccid=bM4ZF70O&simid=608046636088100410&sim=1&cal=0.16442451420029897&cab=0.7877984084880637&cat=0.23209549071618038&car=0.8624813153961136

Answer (score 1):

Looking at his website, I see two main things going on:

1) High contrast imagery. The kind you would get in Lightroom by pushing the Contrast or Clarity sliders to the 80-100 range.

2) Focus on hands as the subject with various props to provide context. This is something nearly every portrait class teaches as a "hack", and is a pictorialist technique (Victorian photographers who sought to replicate what the Renaissance painters did in their portraits). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pictorialism

You now have some keywords to use for Googling to find other photographers who use the same techniques.

Personally, these remind me of two famous photographers.

Firstly, there's Diane Arbus' work. Her photographs are high contrast partly as a result of the chemistry available at the time, but also because they were deliberately printed that way. She was also a portraitist and used a lot of Pictorialist techniques.

Take a look at this for some examples:

[image: High contrast portrait, pushed in the darkroom]

[image: Use of hands in a portrait]

The other early photographer who took a lot of hand pictures is Alfred Stieglitz, who helped establish photography as an artistic medium. His muse/obsession was the painter Georgia O'Keeffe, and he took a large number of pictures of her hands. Just Google "stieglitz o'keeffe hands" and you'll see what I mean.

[image: Stieglitz O'Keeffe hands]

[image: More hands]